# Child theme only loads on home page

Tags: child-theme

I was having the following problem:

I created a child theme, it was 'correct', technically. It even worked and displayed the proper changes, and when I navigated to sub-pages (ie not the home page), the child theme's effects seemed to vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scoured the code in the parent theme for any clues, I found none. The one clue I found was that the 404 page worked as expected, which tipped me off that something was up with the page-templates.

To resolve the issue, I opened a post, changed the page template to another one (for example "contact form"), updated, then changed it back.

I have no idea why that worked, it appears to be a wordpress bug.